# Is there a simple way to get the number of milliseconds since the epoch corresponding to a given date?

Tags: date-and-time

`UnixTime@DateObject@"2017-05-05T01:02:30.5Z"` gives the seconds, rounded to an integer, so I can't simply multiply it by 1000 to get the milliseconds. How can I get milliseconds without doing date arithmetic?

Comment: "...gives the seconds, as an integer, so I can't multiply it by 1000." - I'm having trouble understanding this. Why wouldn't you be able to multiply an integer by 1000?

Comment: Why not use AbsoluteTime instead of UnixTime?

Comment: Sorry, "...gives the seconds, as an integer, so I can't multiply it by 1000." was unclear. I've updated it. I meant that, since the fractional section is gone, I can't multiply it by 1000 to get the millisecond value.

Comment: I'm using UnixTime instead of AbsoluteTime because I want to compute in GMT.

Comment: Try `Block[{$TimeZone = 0}, UnitConvert[DateDifference[DateObject["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"], DateObject["2017-05-05T01:02:30.5Z"], "Seconds"], "Milliseconds"]]`.

Comment: Yes, that works, but you need to change "Seconds" to "Second" and "Milliseconds" to "Millisecond".

Answer (score 1):

There is a fixed offset between [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime) and [`UnixTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnixTime), so you can use [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime) instead of [`UnixTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnixTime) if you want subsecond resolution. For example:

```
ut = (#-2208963600&)@*AbsoluteTime;
```

Then:

```
UnixTime[Today]
ut[Today]
```

> 1509692400
>
> 1509692400

and:

```
UnixTime[Now]
ut[Now]
```

> 1509740426
>
> 1.509740426703258*10^9

For your example:

```
UnixTime @ DateObject @ "2017-05-05T01:02:30.5Z"
ut @ DateObject @ "2017-05-05T01:02:30.5Z" //InputForm
```

> 1493971350
>
> 1.4939713505*^9

Comment: `DateObject @ "2017-05-05T01:02:30.5Z"` is not what you think it is. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144764/5478

Comment: @Kuba I just copied what the OP had, you should probably be commenting on the OP use of that idiom instead. My point was that my version `ut` provides the fractional seconds they wanted.

Comment: That was fyi, nothing more. And yes I could comment on OP but it already has more comments so here it can get more attention.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it doesn't parse the Z at the end. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is `f[d_String] := 
 Module[{do = DateObject[d, TimeZone -> "GMT"]}, 
  1000 * UnixTime@DateObject@do + 
   DateValue[DateObject@do, "Millisecond"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current time in milliseconds since Epoch,

```
ToExpression[ToString[UnixTime[]] <> DateString["Millisecond"]]
```

I don't know how accurate it is given there are two functions called at different times so I can only assume there is a slight variation between the "true" time with milliseconds and this solution.

```
UnixTime[]

1509763110

ToExpression[ToString[UnixTime[]] <> DateString["Millisecond"]]

1509763110487
```